# AppCompat Vector drawable crashed on RadioButton selector

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In selector i try set shape, other - all be ok.
When i change to `<vector>` - app is crashed.
I can set to ImageViev app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon and all ok, but if i set to RadioButton app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_selecton and use for item

```
`<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon" android:state_checked="false"/>`
```

I seen that error for API19, but on API21 all ok!

Crash code:

```
`Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: 
Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton`
```

I use 23.4.0.1 library.

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/a2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:windowNoTitle="true"
    android:id="@+id/container">
<RadioGroup
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/man"
    android:button="@drawable/woman_selector"
    android:radius="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />
    <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/woman"
    android:button="@drawable/man_selector"
    android:radius="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

**woman_selextor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selwoman" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/defwoman" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

**defwoman.xml** (selwoman.xml have only diffirence colors)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" 
                android:id="@+id/shapeBg"> 
            <solid android:color="#B733C6"/>    
            <size android:width="70dp" android:height="70dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:height="70dp"
    android:viewportWidth="70"
    android:viewportHeight="70">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M43 45l-6 0 0 -5c6,-1 11,-6 11,-13 0,-7 -6,-13 -13,-13 -7,0 -13,6 -13,13 0,7
5,12 11,13l0 5 -6 0c-2,0 -2,3 0,3l6 0 0 6c0,2 4,2 4,0l0 -6 6 0c2,0 2,-3
0,-3zm-18 -18c0,-5 5,-10 10,-10 5,0 10,5 10,10 0,5 -5,10 -10,10 -5,0 -10,-5
-10,-10z" />
</vector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And support library:

> Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.4.0.1
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.23.4.0.1
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.23.4.0.1
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.23.4.0.1

I create new app and reproduce this error, [link to App1.sln archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9zvs1jawtxywu5/App1.zip?dl=0)

This perfect working on Android 5.1 but crashed on 4.4.
If remove from drawable item - vector, shape working on 4.4 but without icon.

Comment: can you provide complete axml where radio buttons are used so we can quickly reproduce this?

Comment: @YuriS, i'm add code to my question, main, selector and vector drawable.

Comment: Providing link to the project was the huge help. Was able to reproduce problem quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Activity derive from AppCompatActivity and add static constructor

```
    [Activity (Label = "App1.Droid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
        public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
        {

            static MainActivity()  
            {
                AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;
            }

            protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
            {
```

You will have to change the theme in manifest derived from AppCompat. You can select different themes (I like Dark)

```
    <application android:label="App1.Droid" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"></application>
```

In selectors substitute item with vector by item with drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval"
            android:id="@+id/shapeBg">
      <solid android:color="#fff"/>
      <size android:width="70dp" android:height="70dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/woman_path"/>
</layer-list>
```

woman_path.xml looks like your vector before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:height="70dp"
    android:viewportWidth="70"
    android:viewportHeight="70">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"
      android:pathData="M43 45l-6 0 0 -5c6,-1 11,-6 11,-13 0,-7 -6,-13 -13,-13 -7,0 -13,6 -13,13 0,7
5,12 11,13l0 5 -6 0c-2,0 -2,3 0,3l6 0 0 6c0,2 4,2 4,0l0 -6 6 0c2,0 2,-3
0,-3zm-18 -18c0,-5 5,-10 10,-10 5,0 10,5 10,10 0,5 -5,10 -10,10 -5,0 -10,-5
-10,-10z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked! `static MainActivity()`